# ANTLR how to retrieve the type of token with recursion

Tags: recursion, antlr, antlr4

I'm using the ANTLR4 framework and this is a fragment of my language:

```
r
    :    RN                                                   #RNName
    |   'DLRRelationIntersectionOf' LPAREN r COMMA r RPAREN   #RIntersection
    |   'DLRRelationUnionOf' LPAREN r COMMA r RPAREN          #RUnion
```

As you can see, RN is a terminal node so I can easily process it. But r is a non-terminal node so it can be very complex, like DLRRelationUnionOf(RN1, DLRRelationIntersectionOf(RN2,RN3)).
My goal is to process the *r* node and recursively look for RN.
The problem is that once a retrive the rule r in the code like:

```
DLRParser.RContext recursiveRule =  ctx.r();
```

how can I look into recursiveRule to find out the RNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During its run the parser creates a parse tree (if enabled, which is the default). A parse tree is a tree representation of the items matched. This tree consists of `ParserRuleContext` instances, each with children which represent the matched items in that rule in matching order. So for your `r` context, when matching the second alt, you can find 6 child nodes (one for the literal, one for LPAREN, one for the first sub `r` etc.). You can use those child contexts to access the subentries. If an `RN` was matched you have a terminal node in the first child entry.